# How do I compare two queries in PhpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, phpmyadmin

Usually when I execute a query, it displays

> **V** Showing rows 0 - 10 (200 total, Query took 0.0003 seconds.)

But for some queries it says just:

> Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

I would like to compare two queries and see which one performs faster. But the queries which I would like to compare show the second message.

How do I compare two queries in PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: If you want to do query optimizations, I suggest you do the queries directly in the mysql client.

Comment: Furthermore, avoid the Query cache by saying `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Comment: @RickJames That is some excellent advice! Haven't heard about it before

Comment: I usually say "90% of _production_ systems _should_ have turn it off:  my.cnf: `query_cache_size=0` _and_ `query_cache_type=0`."  (But that takes more typing to say.)  Since you are "comparing two queries" `SQL_NO_CACHE` was more relevant.